# Convert curl with additional parameters into PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, jenkins

Trying to convert a `curl` command for building `Jenkins job`so I can use it in PHP. Here is what I do:

```
<?php

        $testrun_id = "1744";
        $cmd="curl -X POST http://build:f9280f220bfb4c596f83a0@mobile-jenkins.me.com:8080/job/android-job-git/build --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"POST_RESULTS", "value":"true"}, {"name":"RUN_ID", "value":"{$testrun_id}"}, {"name":"CHECK_NAME", "value":"SampleAutomatedPlan"}]}'";
        exec($cmd, $result);

?>
```

Here I am passing 3 parameters to the `jenkins job` and they are  `POST_RESULTS` with value `true`, `RUN_ID` with value of var `$testrun_id` which is `1744` and `CHECK_NAME` whose value is `SamplAutomatedPlan`. When I run this curl command on mac terminal, it works perfectly fine.

What would be the missing things OR errors that gives me `Parse error: parse error on that $cmd="curl..." line` when I try to run this php script?

Comment: you have unescaped double quotes inside the string... it looks like `$cmd = "klsjdklf"sdfsd"Sdfsdf"SDfsdf";` ... where is the end of string? .. php (and another compiler/interpreters) not so smart :)

Comment: Can you write me an example based on my question? I tried applying the escape characters as you and Muhammad has suggested, I still get the parse error.

Comment: Muhammad code actually doesn't have your issue, use it.

Comment: Yeah I see that `;`- semicolon was missing but he fixed and I was dumb enough to not see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes by adding backslashes.

```
$cmd = "curl -X POST http://build:f9280f220bfb4c596f83a0@mobile-jenkins.me.com:8080/job/android-job-git/build --data-urlencode  json='{\"parameter\": [{\"name\":\"POST_RESULTS\", \"value\":\"true\"}, {\"name\":\"RUN_ID\", \"value\":\"{$testrun_id}\"}, {\"name\":\"CHECK_NAME\", \"value\":\"SampleAutomatedPlan\"}]}'";
```

Comment: i get the same error: `Parse error: parse error` is there anything else/even some more escape characters that are missing?

Comment: I see that `;` was missing and thanks for fixing that, worked!